# Podio webhook verification not received by AWS API Gateway

Tags: webhooks, podio

I have setup API Gateway & Lambda to receive webhooks from Podio. I have setup the webhook in Podio with the API Gateway endpoint and have the lambda function set to log out the received event, just to check it is receiving requests.

The endpoint is currently set to receive any type of request. I originally only set it up to receive POST requests but as it was not receiving anything I opened it up.

Because the API Gateway endpoint works when I test it from other various POST/GET request sites, I set up a test endpoint on an old php server and it received the hook verification from Podio.

Why is either:

- Podio not sending the hook requests to API gateway?

or

- API Gateway not receiving posts from Podio?

Comment: Can you please explain in more details what is "API gateway" you have used and how did you verify that it can receive other POST/GET requests?

Comment: [API gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) can be used to create an end point that passed the requested data to in my case a [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function. I have tested it with curl posts, the Chrome rest easy extension and requests from one of our dev sites.

Comment: Can you please also share example of web_hook url you are using?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio this is the live webhook: [https://ecr7o486ei.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/beta/](https://ecr7o486ei.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/beta/)

Comment: There is nothing special in this URL, so I don't see why it may not work. Have you tried that all again? ( click 'Verify' webhook from Podio UI and check if request came)

Comment: The issue was with the data mapping on API gateway. I was expecting to receive JSON formatted data as per documentation. But it was sending form data which I needed to map after it was received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution came after I discovered how to turn on the CloudWatch logs for API Gateway. I discovered that the data being sent was not JSON formatted as I was expecting, but x-www-form-urlencoded instead.
I then setup a mapping template:

```
#set( $inputRoot = $input.path('$') )
#set( $item = {} )
{
    #foreach( $param in $inputRoot.split('&') )
        #set( $t = $param.split('=') )
        "$t[0]":"$t[1]",
    #end
    "null":"null"
}
```

which handles both the hook verification requests but also the webhook posts from Podio, this mapped data then passes successfully into Lambda.

*I use the "null":"null" at the end so I can run the simple foreach loop and still retain valid JSON output*